# button automatically triggers "click" when press "enter key"

Tags: javascript, button, click, enter, onkeyup

In my website, I have a search box with a button. an auto suggest box will appear when search in the box. I added keyup event on js for move the selection up and down. And on enter press, go to a js file for the ajax call. The same thing i wrote for `click` event too. But when I select a list item using `up or down key` and press `enter key`, it automatically refresh the page with an additional `?` in the `url`. I am using `Progressive — Responsive Multipurpose HTML Template`. Dont know whether it is an inbuilt code in it.

my html is

```
<form name="search-form">
        <input class="search-string form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search here" name="" id="navSearchInput" autocomplete="off">
            <button class="search-submit" id="search_submit">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="16px" height="16px" viewBox="0 0 16 16" enable-background="new 0 0 16 16" xml:space="preserve">
          <path fill="#231F20" d="M12.001,10l-0.5,0.5l-0.79-0.79c0.806-1.021,1.29-2.308,1.29-3.71c0-3.313-2.687-6-6-6C2.687,0,0,2.687,0,6
          s2.687,6,6,6c1.402,0,2.688-0.484,3.71-1.29l0.79,0.79l-0.5,0.5l4,4l2-2L12.001,10z M6,10c-2.206,0-4-1.794-4-4s1.794-4,4-4
          s4,1.794,4,4S8.206,10,6,10z"></path>
        </svg>
      </button>
    </form>
```

and java script code is

```
$("#navSearchInput").keyup(TriggerSearch);

function TriggerSearch(e) {
    var search_string = encodeURIComponent($("#navSearchInput").val());
    e = e || window.event;
    var keycode;
    if (window.event) {
        keycode = e.which ? window.event.which : window.event.keyCode;
    }
    var key = e.which;
    switch (key) {
    case 38:
        break;
    case 40:
        break;
    case 13:
        e.preventDefault();
        search_product();
        break;
    default:
        if (search_string != "") {
       //default code
      }

function search_product(e) {
//code goes here
}
```

What is the problem with it? Please help...

Comment: When you hit enter the button will do its normal thing: submit the form. Is your `case 13: ...` inside a function ?

Comment: @putvande, i urdated the case section..Please take a look

Comment: but the button is not a submit button.. it is <button>

Comment: Yep. But the `<button>` type is `submit` by default. Just do `<button type="button">`.

Comment: YUP, hitting enter on my site was submitting the form, but also simulating a click on another button which wasn't defined to be of [type="submit"].  Very sneaky, glad I came across putvande's comment!